# Is it possible to tap into Windows 10's Cortana API for Python?

Tags: python, api, artificial-intelligence, windows-10, speech

I am currently working on a home automation project. When Windows 10 was released my speech recognition API became incompatible. Is there an openly available API to use Cortana, if not is it possible to tap into the speech recognition API?

Python 2.7
Windows 10
The Dragonfly Speech API is no longer working, it used the windows voice recognition.

My ultimate goal is to not use a launch phrase, I want my AI to listen to everything I say. If I randomly ask a question I want an answer. I have the AI part covered but the voice input it my biggest problem.

Thanks for the help, I am looking forward to the answers!

(Note: This is not a duplicate question due to the Windows 10 complications.)

Comment: If there is a api for Cortana (I'm not sure if there is) then you can get to it with IronPython (Python on the .net runtime).

Comment: Ah Nice thinking Burhan Khalid,
I will look into it, I have a feeling it will be a little hackish, since regular Desktop apps cant take advantage of the API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently visited one of Microsoft's offices in Germany and asked some of the Cortana evangelists if Cortana would be open-sourced, or if they were planning on developing a speech recognition API. They told me about the possibility of launching foreground apps with Cortana, but said an open API is not in the pipeline for now.

It may be better to look into the Google speech recognition API:
https://progfruits.wordpress.com/2014/05/31/using-google-speech-api-from-python/

It is limited to 50 requests a day, but the accuracy is fairly good.

Comment: Thanks for the information, that saved a lot of time.